# Перегрузка метода в чужом классе в Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть код стороннего разработчика: Typescript, Angular. В этом коде нужно откорректировать формат вывода некоторых не примитивных данных, представленных объектами классов (например встроенный тип Date). Вывод полей осуществляется методом toString() этих объектов.
Можно ли произвести перегрузку метода в чужом классе Typescript (Javascript), например `Date.toString()`?

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под перегрузкой метода?

Comment: @Grundy Замену метода в чужом(встроенном)  классе из своего кода

Comment: Приведи пример того, что ты хочешь в вопросе. Как бы ты хотел чтобы выглядел код

Comment: В большинстве случаев ты можешь переписать конкретный метод объектов, либо в прототипе обычным присвоением. Но могут быть варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно переопределить метод и вызывать базовый (или даже не вызывать):

```
class MyDate extends Date {
    toString() {
        return 'my: ' + super.toString();
    }
}

md = new MyDate();
md.toString();  // my: Tue May 29 2018 10:16:20 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))
```

Comment: Вариант с наследованием я знаю. Но хотелось бы как то подсунуть новый метод в старый класс.

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве случаев можно переписать конкретный метод объекта, либо прототипа обычным присваиванием.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.toString = function() {
  return "custom date: " + this.getDate();
}
console.log(d.toString());

Date.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "custom prototype date: " + this.getDate();
}
console.log(new Date().toString());
```

Однако это не всегда возможно, и для самого объекта и для его прототипа можно быть запрещено изменение какого-то конкретного свойства и в этом случае ничего сделать не получится.

---

Так как речь про сторонний код, то возможно в нем может существовать настройка формата, либо, как крайний случай, поменять нужный сторонний код, так как расширение прототипов встроенных объектов может повлиять на другие части.